# Возможно ли переполнение при вычитании в компараторе?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, сортировка, любой-язык, переполнение

Рассмотрим сортировку, у которой в компараторе в качестве результата используется разность сравниваемых элементов

```
a.sort((x, y) => x-y)
```

Очевидно, что при целочисленных типах данных этот алгоритм подвержен переполнению, приводящему к неверному результату. Такой пример довольно лекго составить:

```js
console.log([1<<31, 1].sort((x, y) => x-y|0))
```

А как насчёт вещественных чисел? Подвержены ли они проблеме переполнения?

Я могу придумать пример, где разность двух Infinity даёт NaN, но не могу придумать ситуацию, в которой это бы сказалось на сортировке - ведь все бесконечности равны, а разности с другими значениями поставят их на нужное место.

```js
console.log([Infinity, 1, -Infinity, Infinity].sort((x, y) => x-y))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Представление целых чисел со знаком имеет зацикленную структуру за счет использования "дополнительного кода" для представления отрицательных значений. Это и является причиной того, что выполняя вроде бы обычное сложение двух целых чисел можно получить отрицательное число, если нет контроля переполнений, тоже касается сложения двух отрицательных.

В представлении вещественных чисел ([IEEE 754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)) цикличность отсутствует, знак числа хранится отдельным битом. Зато присутствует два нуля (+0, -0), собственно чтобы их не было и вводили дополнительный код в представлении целых. Переполнение мантиссы не возможно, т.к. из мантиссы вытесняются лишние младшие биты после вычисления порядка результата. Порядок хранится как целое без знака и его максимальное значение обрабатывается особым образом, поэтому вместо переполнения получаются либо бесконечности, либо `NaN`.

Таким образом сам формат вещественных чисел ([IEEE 754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)) не допускает ошибки переполнения при выполнении стандартных арифметических операций.

Answer (score 2):

Если для сортировки массива чисел с плавающей точкой использовать компаратор наподобие следующего (здесь и далее все примеры на C++):

```
bool Compare(const double &a, const double &b)
{
    return a - b > 0.0;
}
```

то проблемы возникнуть могут.

---

Во-первых, массив исходных данных может содержать ["*нечисла*" (*Not-a-Number*, `NaN`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). `NaN` является неупорядоченным (unordered) по отношению к любым другим числам с плавающей точкой, включая самого себя. Это означает, что если по крайней мере один операнд бинарных операторов `<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, `>` — `NaN`, то результат сравнения `false`; если по крайней мере один из операндов бинарного оператора `!=` — `NaN`, то результат сравнения `true` (стоит заметить, что согласно стандарту вычислений с плавающей точкой IEEE 754-2008, операторы сравнения могут генерировать исключение в случае, если по крайней мере один из операндов — `NaN`).

`NaN` также характеризуется особой арифметикой. Например, если по крайней мере один из операндов бинарного `-` — `NaN`, то результат `NaN`.

Такие свойства `NaN`'ов в совокупности с представленным выше компаратором могут отрицательно сказаться на результатах сортировки. Для примера рассмотрим сортировку вставками ([Пример](https://ideone.com/k02ioM)):

```
void InsertionSort(vector<double> &vect)
{
    for (size_t i = 1; i < vect.size(); ++i)
        for (size_t j = i; j > 0 && Compare(vect[j], vect[j - 1]); --j)
            swap(vect[j], vect[j - 1]);
}
```

Ни один элемент массива `{1.0, NaN, 2.0, NaN, 1.0}` после такой сортировки не будет перемещён. На каждой итерации цикла `i` при помощи функции `Compare` будет сравниваться пара чисел с плавающей точкой. И каждый раз в этой паре будет присутствовать `NaN`. И каждый раз результат сравнения будет `false`, а значит не будет произведено ни одного обмена элементов вектора.

---

Второй пример связан с денормализованными (субнормальными) числами.

Если бы удалось подобрать два таких числа `a` и `b`, что `a > b`, но `a - b == 0`, то возникли бы проблемы с сортировкой. Ведь `a` больше `b`, но компаратор говорит, что `a` не больше `b`, а значит алгоритм сортировки не обязан менять числа `a` и `b` местами.

Википедия [говорит](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), что в формате  IEEE 754-2008 разность двух неравных, но близких друг к другу чисел, не бывает равна нулю. И обеспечивается это, отчасти, благодаря денормализованным числам.

Взглянем повнимательнее на числа с плавающей точкой двойной точности. А именно на минимальное положительное нормализованное число (`min`), число следующее непосредственно за предыдущим (в сторону единицы, `min_1`), разность двух предыдущих (`diff = min_1 - min`) и минимальное положительное денормализованное число (`denorm_min`):

```
min        == 2.22507385850720138e-308
min_1      == 2.22507385850720188e-308
diff       == 4.94065645841246544e-324
denorm_min == 4.94065645841246544e-324
```

Можно заметить, что разность двух нормализованных чисел представляет собой денормализованное значение.

Некоторые процессоры (в частности, с поддержкой SSE2), позволяют сбрасывать до нуля (flush to zero) результат арифметического выражения, если он денормализованный. Т.е. в данном конкретном случае, разность двух нормализованных, неравных чисел `min` и `min_1` вполне может получится равной нулю, а значит можно сконструировать пример некорректной сортировки.

Воспользуемся Visual Studio, функцией [_controlfp_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9676k6h.aspx) и напишем небольшой [пример](http://rextester.com/LLJV81140):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <float.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#pragma fenv_access (on)

bool Compare(const double &a, const double &b)
{
    return a - b > 0.0;
}

int main()
{
    double min = numeric_limits<double>::min();
    double min_1 = nextafter(min, 1.0);

    vector<double> v = {min, min_1, min, 1.0, 2.0};
    _controlfp_s(nullptr, _DN_FLUSH, _MCW_DN);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), Compare);
    for (auto val : v)
        cout << val << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Вектор до сортировки:
2.22507385850720138e-308 2.22507385850720188e-308 2.22507385850720138e-308 1.0 2.0

Вектор после сортировки:
2.0 1.0 2.225073858507201**38**e-308 2.225073858507201**88**e-308 2.225073858507201**38**e-308

Хоть пример довольно таки надуманный, но не невозможный на практике (особенно с учетом того, что судя по документации, [некоторые компиляторы](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522985) по-умолчанию включают опцию flush to zero на всех уровнях оптимизации, больших чем -O0).